# IIS default installed web site stops responding if i log off

Tags: iis

Maybe a rookie question though I work with IIS for a few years now.
I installed standard IIS on Windows 10 Professional PC. I use another computer to open default IIS web site hosted on that first PC. When I log off from first computer the default site doesnt open on second computer. When I log back in the site opens. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out WIFI was in use and that was turning off when user was logging off.